# Extent changing in ArcGIS Pro when shapefile added to map which only had basemap?

Tags: extents, arcgis-online-basemaps, arcgis-pro

Using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop:

In ArcMap:

- Open a Blank Map
- Add Basemap of Imagery (but any basemap will do)
- Zoom to Australia (but any area will do)
- Add the countries shapefile from Natural Earth (but any shapefile that covers an area much larger than where the basemap has been zoomed to will do)
- Notice how the extent does not change which to me is the expected behaviour

In ArcGIS Pro:

- Create a project using Map.aptx
- Change the Basemap to Imagery (but any basemap will do)
- Zoom to Australia (but any area will do)
- Add the countries shapefile from Natural Earth (but any shapefile that covers an area much larger than where the basemap has been zoomed to will do)
- Notice how the extent changes to become the extent of the shapefile that was just added

I think the software behaviour observed in the last dot point is a bug, and am wondering if anybody has already reported this and has a bug (NIM) number that can be used to track its resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I submitted this to local Esri support they responded:

> AcrGIS Pro is designed to interact with data differently than ArcMAp.
>   The zooming to a input layers extent, is a modification within ArcGIS
>   Pro which is designed to make it easier for users to interect with
>   their data. This is not considered a bug and does not have a NIM
>   number.

I still think it is a bug and will be interested to see if this software behaviour is changed to match that of ArcMap in a later release.

Comment: I suppose this is a bit opinion based on what should happen, but if I don't have any data loaded yet, I like that it navigates the display to my new data.

Comment: @KHibma I guess I find it disconcerting to be looking at a detailed basemap using an extent, deciding to add another layer to get a better understanding of what is going on within that extent, and then to be shown lots of data at a broader scale that I am not interested in at that time.

Comment: @KHibma On the other hand, today I opened a Map which presented a basemap centred on the US and by adding some Queensland data it jumped straight to Queensland which saved me a "Zoom To Layer".  Maybe this behaviour should be configurable (if it is not) because I suspect ratio of times each user wants to do one versus the other will influence their reaction to the change from ArcMap.